# Xamarin build hangs

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, msbuild

I am building Android Xamarin solution in my Windows machine using msbuild.

Sometimes, in following step, the build hangs. therefore no successful build.

```
Executing package --non-constant-id -f -m -M path-to-file\lp\13\jl\res\..\manifest\AndroidManifest.xml -J obj\Release\android\src -S obj\Release\res -S path-to-file\lp\13\jl\res -S path-to-file\lp\16\jl\res -S path-to-file\lp\18\jl\res -S path-to-file\lp\19\jl\res -S path-to-file\lp\21\jl\res -S path-to-file\lp\22\jl\res -S path-to-file\lp\23\jl\res -S path-to-file\lp\25\jl\res -S path-to-file\lp\26\jl\res -I
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-27\android.jar" --auto-add-overlay (TaskId:1677)
```

Comment: You can use Ctrl+Pause in console to force VS compiler to stop, and then rebuild.

Comment: @JoeLv-MSFT thanks. But i build in jenkins usually. i am wondering is there any thing to be done, so we don't encounter hang situation

Comment: Hi, By `i build in jenkins usually.`, I am not sure what is it, but, build hanging will occurs in VS, also on other IDE will happen this. So I usually force to stop it, and rebuild, maybe I will delete the bin and obj folder and then restart VS.